# Simple google login doesn't connect to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-oauth, passport.js

It is my first time implementing google login. I am using [react-google-login on the front end, which is a library based on react 16 but aside from that should work](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dump-work/react-google-login). On the backend I am using passport with google oauth2. The issue is that while the google popup opens and I can click on my profile, after the popup closes by itself, I get no response on the server side. Here is my front end code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';

function App() {
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    // Handle the Google login response here
    console.log(response);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <GoogleLogin
        clientId="882516377786-e6dfholj9nsma16kravu3k5v103q6lqp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login with Google"
        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
        onFailure={responseGoogle}
        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my backend code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: "myClientId",
      clientSecret: "mySecret",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      // Implement your logic here to handle the authenticated user's data
      console.log("Google Profile:", profile);
      return cb(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"],
  })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log("Authentication success");
    res.redirect("/"); // Redirect to the home page or wherever you want
  }
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

// Error handler for unhandled errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Here is a screenshot from google console: [image: Google Console Screenshot]

Here is the link the popup calls: *https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Flocalhost%3A5173%3Fid%3Dauth615863&response_type=permission id_token&scope=email profile openid&openid.realm&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id=myClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5173&prompt&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2&service=lso&o2v=1&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow*

There are no error on the popup, everything goes smoothly. There is no data received on the server side. How do I receive the user profile in the express server?

Comment: What does your terminal say in the /auth/google/callback route?

Comment: Nothing, it seems the route isn't reached